# C++ Linked List: Memory Leak Issue

Tags: c++, templates, memory, linked-list

I'm trying to create a linked list that can append/delete/display items. I got the header and the test complete, and it seems to have worked. It successfully appended, deleted, and displayed the results. However, immediately after the results were displayed, I get a runtime pop-up saying "Debug Assertion Failed! Expression:_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)"

So I did some debugging, and obviously it's a memory leak (or at least I'm pretty sure it is). I swear my destructor was written correctly. My test works, the linked list works (plus it's member functions) works, so what am I doing wrong?

Here's my class declarations, default constructor, and destructor

```
template <typename T>
class Node
{
public:
    T Value;
    Node<T> *next;
    Node(T nodeValue)
    {
        value = nodeValue;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
private:
    Node<T> *head;
public:
    LinkedList()
    { head = NULL; }

   ~LinkedList()
    {
        Node<T> *temp;
        Node<T> *nextNode;

        temp = head;

        while (temp != NULL)
        {
            nextNode = temp->next;
            delete temp;
            temp = nextNode;
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the rest of the Linked List (even though it works but in case you ask)

```
void appendNode(T newValue)
{
    Node<T> *newNode;
    Node<T> *temp;

    newNode = new Node<T>(newValue);

    if (!head)
        head = newNode;
    else
    {
        temp = head;

        while (temp->next)
            temp = temp->next;

        temp->next = newNode;
    }
}

void deleteNode(T searchValue)
{
    Node<T> *temp;
    Node<T> *prev = NULL;

    if (!head)
        return;

    if (head->value == searchValue)
    {
        temp = head->next;
        delete head;
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = head;
        while (temp != NULL && temp->value != searchValue)
        {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if (temp)
        {
            prev->next = temp->next;
            delete temp;
        }
    }
}

void displayList() const
{
    Node<T> *temp;
    temp = head;
    while (temp)
    {
        cout << temp->value << " ";
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you follow [the rule of three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28C%2B%2B_programming%29)?

Comment: I have went over your code and I've tested it, couldn't reproduce the error. Everything in your class seems as it should be. Do you by any chance have something extra in your main() function?

Comment: `so what am I doing wrong?`  Your "error-free" linked list class is not error-free.  Where is your user-defined copy constructor and assignment operator?  Without these functions, your linked list cannot be used reliably, and I suspect this is the issue.